Orcad 17.2: package editing
Orcad 17.2: I have 2 parts for same pkg. The layout is for both. 1 is in each pkg. I want to add the part in the 2nd pkg to the 1st and increase the parts per package to 2.
I have opened the part with Edit>part then View Package which brings up a little spreadsheet I can't do anything with. I can't find anything to edit the parts per package.
I have googled but can't find this answer. I have found enough to get me this far, but I am stuck. This should not be this hard.
What am I doing wrong?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Specifically, I have a part package for an EF86 vacuum tube w/o the filament. I have a part package for the filament called EF86Fil each package has 1 part per package. I need to add the filament to the main package, so the new package will have 2 selectable parts will be labeled something like V1-1 and V1-2 respectively.
How do I combine these 2 into 1? I don't know how to make it any clearer than that.

I just found a video that details creating a new multi-section part from scratch. From this, it looks like maybe I cannot leverage the existing graphics work done by editing the existing part. Can someone confirm or deny this?
